# css :before visible when overflow hidden

Tags: css, overflow

there is possible to display something befere? when overflow is hidden?  or maybe can we specifiy with side will be hidden from overflow?
for ex:

```css
.before {
  width: 200px;
  margin: 30px;
  background-color: blue;
  height: 30px;
  position: relative;
}

.before:before {
  content: "221";
  color: blue;
  font-size: 15px;
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  left: -20px;
  top: -20px;
}

#ex2 {
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div id='ex1' class='before'>Wisible text with css before, more text, more and more... but </div>
<div id='ex2' class='before'>hidden overflow text with css before... more and more text</div>
```

Comment: No you can't have `overflow: hidden;` pick and choose what content is displayed and what is not. If it overflows the container then it will be hidden.

Answer (score 3):

If you declare an element to have `overflow: hidden` it will apply to all content, including `before` and `after` elements. There is no way to disable the hidden value for a specific child.

Consider wrapping your content in a div with a maximum width and height of its parent, and setting `oveflow: hidden` on that div instead. The root element's `before` and `after` pseudoelements will exist outside the wrapper so won't be affected.

```css
.before {
  width: 200px;
  margin: 30px;
  background-color: blue;
  height: 30px;
  position: relative;
}

.before:before {
  content: "221";
  color: blue;
  font-size: 15px;
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  left: -20px;
  top: -20px;
}

#ex2 > .wrapper {
  overflow: hidden;
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id='ex1' class='before'><div class="wrapper">Visible text with css before, more text, more and more... but </div></div>
<div id='ex2' class='before'><div class="wrapper">Hidden overflow text with css before... more and more text</div></div>
```